# Static Shock from Computer (CPU Fan)

Tags: cpu, desktop, fan

I was at a desktop earlier (powered off, power supply switched off, plugged in with grounded plug), and when touching the top middle of the CPU fan (where the sticker is) I got a static shock. I then touched the metal part of the case to ground myself - but would the CPU or other components possibly be damaged from this? The computer is running right now and everything seems normal, but wasn't sure if the CPU is grounded while in the socket or not or if the shock can travel from the fan to the CPU.

If the CPU is operating normally now - does that mean that there wasn't any damage to it from the static shock? Or is it possible that the lifespan can be shortened or something?

Comment: So, you didn't notice any damage while being right in front of the computer, but you expect people to diagnose that damage over the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the computer is connected to a grounded plug and the grounded plug is properly wired to a correctly wired circuit, there is minimal chance of problems.

A static shock occurs when there is a difference in the charges between two surfaces (your body and the computer, in this case).

While it can be damaging, and technicians are generally recommended to wear grounding devices when working on computers, this is because you normally work on a computer that is not itself grounded because you have disconnected it from power in order to work on it.

If the computer itself is properly grounded the charge of the shock is carried through the frame (chassis) of the computer, down the ground wire of the power cord, and into the ground of the house circuit.

Comment: Thanks - does the charge going through the frame apply even with the CPU fan though? I'm wondering because it uses plastic pins to snap into the motherboard.

Comment: What do you mean? The current does not have a reason to go especially to the fan. Yes, if there are aged and already damaged components a change of charge across this component could cause it to break, but in normal components there will be no special damage to the fan any more than any other component. Do you have reason to worry?

Comment: Current takes the path of least resistance, which is the reason, you should make that you and not your motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

You got a ESD discharge across the fan sticker into fan electronics, which is connected to mainboard ground via 4-wire leads, which is connected to Earth ground via chassis, then into PSU, and power cord. Apparently you have a really dry air around, some synthetic clothes, and got charged yourself to a pretty high level from your movement and/or friction with the desk or furniture or carpet.

Next time you reach inside an open PC and touch internals, discharge yourself into PC metal chassis first. You apparently were lucky to touch the fan first, otherwise you could hit some more sensitive part of your PC, and it will likely die (given your bad ESD environment).